# Adobe LiveCycle ES2 JavaScript if-else, else not working

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I have been trying for a few days, to get a simple `if/else` script to work. 
The issue I am having is when I check syntax, it says:

> error illegal use if reserved word else

The script I am using is:

```
if (aira.delsec.presence = "hidden")
airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1)
airb.presence = "visible"
aira.delsec.presence = "visible";
else
airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1)
```

Also, I have tried:

```
if (aira.delsec.presence = "hidden");{ 
airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1)
airb.presence = "visible"
aira.delsec.presence = "visible";
} else
{
aira.delsec.presence = "visible";
}
```

If I remove the `else` then the `if` statement works fine. I am really pulling out my hair and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript syntax is wrong. Try:

```
if (aira.delsec.presence === "hidden") { // use an opening brace, and...
                                         //   === to check for equality...
                                         //   because = assigns a value
  airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1);      // end with a semi-colon
  airb.presence = "visible";             // end with a semi-colon
  airb.delsec.presence = "visible";      // end with a semi-colon
} else {                                 // use closing and opening braces
  airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1);      // end with a semi-colon
}                                        // use a closing brace
```

Be sure to use a [linting tool to validate your JavaScript](http://www.jslint.com/) as you learn. You will become familiar with the proper syntax more quickly.

Comment: hi thank you, but when i try this it completly ignores the condition and whether or not aira.delsec is hidden or visible it will add rows to my table. if i add the semicolon in at the end of the condition then the if statement works but the else statement does not.

Comment: using the website you recommended i found that the following seems to work: `if (aira.delsec.presence === "hidden") { 
  airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1);    
  airb.presence = "visible";           
  aira.delsec.presence = "visible";    
} else {                               
  airb.tblair._Row1.addInstance(1);
}` :)

Comment: Good catch @jpee - I've updated the answer.  Up-vote if helpful.